# Is editing part of Youtube audio in a video possible via the Youtube editor?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

I have an uploaded video and I want to cut sections of audio (strong language) or add beeps on top without reuploading the video.

Comment: related questions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/146790/159892 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136886/159892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way to do that. You can completely replace your audio with one of YouTube's free audio tracks ***or*** you can re-mix your audio at home and re-upload the video; then change the upload date:

[image: YouTube's Studio - Recording Date Editor]

According to [YouTube's Audio Editor help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/94316?hl=en) you can choose when the added audio will start, and the mix level (how loud it will be), but complete audio editing and muxing (replacing one track) isn't available.